# What are LOCAL_HEADER_LIBRARIES in Android.mk?

Tags: makefile, android.mk

While generating a new library we can specify dependencies in Android.mk .For Example there are header dependencies which can be specified in LOCAL_C_INCLUDES, then there are library dependencies like LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES and LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES.

But ,I could not find anything in Android documentation(mentioned below) for LOCAL_HEADER_LIBRARIES
https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/vndk/build-system

Comment: We have no idea what in the world you're talking about.  Based on the tags, something to do with android I guess...??

Comment: Changed body..is it understadable ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this from my lead. He said, we include header file's Android.bp. These header files are header file for LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES.

That's what I understand